# How do I stop Outlook from asking me to choose a profile?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, user-profiles, microsoft-outlook-2003

Microsoft Outlook 2003:

I used to have two profiles with my Outlook, but I deleted it and now only have one. It is still asking me for what profile to choose. I have tried selecting the option to set it as my default multiple times, yet it still asks me. How can I stop it from asking me?

Comment: You are my hero for asking this!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Mail Setup can be found in the Control Panel (Mail), Outlook has to be closed to apply these settings.

- Open **Control Panel**
- Open **Mail** in Control Panel
- Under **Profiles**: Select - **Show Profiles**
- Select Radio Button - **Always Use this Profile** (Outlook - in Drop Down)

Comment: Excellent! Had to figure out where the Mail Setup was, but I did finally get it to work. Appreciate the help.

Comment: You are my hero for answering this!

Comment: To find Mail Setup: go to Control Panels, then in the search box, type "Mail". Click that control panel and then choose "Show Profiles". (Note that all of this is *outside* of Outlook itself - it is a Windows thing.)

Comment: @hayoo Even if I did what you said already, it happens all the time.