# Outlook 2010 -- always asking to "choose profile"

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, user-profiles

I'm on Windows 7, using Office 2010. Every time I close Outlook it asks me to "choose profile" in a dialog box.

I have only 1 profile, and, after reviewing this site, went into the control panel, "mail", "show profiles" -- i have only 1 profile called "outlook", and the button "always use this profile" is marked/filled in. Moreover, on the "always use this profile" drop down menu contains only one profile, so nothing to choose.

Any thoughts???

Comment: You are asked to choose a profile when you close Outlook or when you open it?

Comment: Maybe some help here (in case you're using "Google Sync"): http://superuser.com/questions/259941/outlook-2010-keeps-asking-to-select-profile-when-google-calendar-sync-starts

Answer (score 4):

In Windows 7, click the Start button, and then click Control Panel.

**And Do the following:**

- Click User Accounts, and then click Mail.***In Classic view,***
- Double-click Mail.**Note:***The Mail icon won't appear unless you
  have Outlook installed and have run the program at least once.*
- The Mail Setup dialog box opens.
- Click Show Profiles. Under **"When starting Microsoft Office Outlook"**, use this profile.
- Click "Always use this profile" and voila **FIX**

*This work with [Google Calendar Sync](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=89955) Installed*

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Google Calendar Sync installed?  It will try and access data and the error is similar

Answer (score -2):

[Here is your answer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/configure-outlook-to-prompt-you-to-choose-a-profile-when-started-HA010271136.aspx):

1. Mail
2. Show profiles
3. Always Use this profile

Comment: OP explicitly said in the question that *Always use this profile* is already enabled.