# How do I stop Outlook from asking me to choose a profile over and over again?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, gmail, user-profiles

I have the same problem as mentioned in this post:
[How do I stop Outlook from asking me to choose a profile?](https://superuser.com/questions/76932/how-do-i-stop-outlook-from-asking-me-to-choose-a-profile)

But unfortunately the solution doesn't help. It was already set to this required setting and when I try to register a new profile from that dialog I get the following error:

[image]

Moreover, Outlook asks me not only to choose that profile when the programme is running but when it is turned off, too! Could this problem be caused by the google calendar sync?

http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=89955

Answer (score 0):

MAPI is the primary API that push/pulls data from the exchange server. I am pretty sure that the error you are seeing is informing you that you are not authorized to create new Profiles on the Exchange Server (hence a time out for logging on). But I would imagine that creating a new profile would not resolve your issue.